# Laravel route list at terminal

Tags: laravel, terminal, routes

Route List Image

[image: 1]

Why my terminal does not showing full path of the routes? Im using windows 11, and windows terminal. Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "full path"? That it does not show your domain? In that case, this is default command behaviour.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).